# Laravel - display data from using data ranges

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display data based on ranges within a drop down menu list.I currently have singular values where i would select the value 10 and it would display all values that = 10.

Now i want to have a drop down menu with the options of 5-10, 11-15, 16-20 and i expect it to display all data within those ranges. See code below

Search.php

```xml
<select name="distance" id="distance" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
    <option value="">Choose an item</option>
    @foreach($distances as $distance)
        <option value="{{ $distance }}">{{ $distance }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Search.Controller.php

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $distances = DB::table('posts')->select('distance')->distinct()->get()->pluck('distance');

    $postsInRange = $request->has('distance')
        ? Post::where('distance', $request->distance)->get()
        : [];

    return view('Pages.search', [
        'distances' => $distances,
        'posts' => $postsInRange
    ]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // This will return all request data to your screen.
    return $request->all();
    return view('Pages.search');
}
```

How would i manage to display the the data using data ranges instead of singular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection's `groupBy` function:

```php
$distancesByGroup = DB::table('posts')
    ->distinct()
    ->pluck('distance')
    ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return (int) ((int) $item / 5);
    });
```

And on your blade:

```php
@foreach($distancesByGroup as $group => $distances)

    <optgroup label="{{ $group * 5 }} - {{ ($group + 1) * 5 }}">

    @foreach($distances as $distance)
        <option value="{{ $distance }}">{{ $distance }}</option>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Note: I haven't tested it but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Sorry can you just explain the <optgroup label="{{ $group * 5 }} - {{ ($group + 1) * 5 }}">

Comment: @TheCodingKid you want to display ranges as '5-10', '10-15' etc. this code displays thees ranges: "1*5 - (1+1)*5", "2*5 - (2+1)*5" etc.

Comment: @TheCodingKid and the [optgroup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) is a html tag to group related options on your dropdown.

Comment: I am receiving error here: ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return (int) $item / 5;
    });   it says syntax error _> required

Comment: @TheCodingKid my bad, there was an extra `;` check my updated answer.

Comment: having ran the code i now get this error: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer